# Tautological consequence and counterexamples

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I know that in order to check if `Q` is a tautological consequence of `P1, P2, ..., Pn` I can look at the truth table.

If, wherever `P1, P2, ..., Pn` are true also `Q` is true, than `Q` is a tautological consequence of `P1, P2, ..., Pn`.

I also know that if I can't find a counterexample, that is a row of the truth table where `P1, P2, ..., Pn` are true and `Q` false, then I can assert that `Q` is a tautological consequence of `P1, P2, ..., Pn`.

I can't understand why the last thing is true. Intuitively if I can't find a counterexample, I cannot say anything, nor that it is true nor that it is false.

The problem is that my intuition is wrong.

How can I understand that fact?

Comment: If the statement that "there exists a row with every $p_i = 1$ and $q=0$" is false, then the opposite is true.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is a finite number of rows to check, you can check them all one by one. If you didn't find any row for which $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ are True and $Q$ is False, then this means that in all rows for which $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ are True, $Q$ is True, too.

Comment: What if I restrict the possibilities by choosing an interpretation where the premises cannot be all true at the same moment. I will never find a counterexample, but I will not also find a case where all premises are true and the consequence is true. What can I say now?

Comment: Then you can say one of two things: a) The interpretation is not correct and you should go for another one, or b) the interpretation is fine and the choice of $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ is such that it is impossible for all of them to be true at the same time (in other words, the set of $P_i$ is inconsistent). In this case, any formula (and not just $Q$) is a tautological consequence of $P_1,\ldots,P_n$. If you want details on why is that, I suggeste you make another question for it.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\mathcal P=1$ to mean every component $P_i$ is true. We say the statements $P_1,\ldots, P_n$ tautologically imply $Q$ if and only if for every row in the truth table
$$\mathcal P=1 \Rightarrow Q=1\tag{1} $$
Negate the former statement. There exists a row in the truth table satisfying
$$\mathcal P=1 \quad \&\quad Q=0\tag{2} $$
To show there is no tautological implication, it suffices to show statement (2) is true (find a counterexample). If no such counterexample exists, then statement (1) must be true, but that means the statements $P_i$ tautologically imply $Q$.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand why the last thing is true. Intuitively if I can't find a counterexample, I cannot say anything, nor that it is true nor that it is false.
>
> The problem is that my intuition is wrong.

Your intuition is not *exactly* wrong. Failing to find something is not enough prove that it cannot be found. However....

The key is being certain that the exploration is *exhaustive*; that is being sure that no cases remain unexamined.  Thus you have not merely failed to find a counter example, but *have* successfully demonstrated that one *cannot* be found.  That the conclusion *must* be true for *all* interpretations where the premises are all true (because you have indeed verified that this is so for every one).

Answer (score 0):

One can always fear not to have checked correctly all the lines of the truth table.

So the most secure method is to **rephrase the " tautological consequence test" in terms of corresponding conditional.**

The assertion " Q is a tautological consequence of premises P1, P2, P3...Pn " is equivalent to the assertion

**" the conditional formula  [(P1&P2&P3&...&Pn) --> Q ] is a tautology ".**

Using this rephrasing , **you make a truth-table for this last conditional formula,  and you only have to look at the last column of your truth table**. If you have only the truth value T in this column, it is guaranteed that Q is a tautological consequence of your set of premises. If you have at least one time the value F in the last column, you know Q is not a tautological consequence.

Now, to answer precisely your question ( regarding what you point as difficult to understand). Knowing that ( A --> B) is the same thing as "it is not the case that A is true and B is false", you can seee that the following 4 assertions are equivalent.

(1) the formula ( P1&P2&P3...&Pn) **-->** Q ) is a tautology,in other words, is true in all possible cases ( all possible " interpretation")

(2) For all possible interpretation ***i***  **if** premises P1, P2, P3...Pn are all true in ***i*** , **then** Q is true in ***i***

( Here, we quantify over the set of all possible interpretations)

(3) There is **no** possible interpretation ***i*** such that **P1, P2, P3...Pn** are all **true** in i and **Q is not** true in ***i***

( In order to pass from (2) to (3)  we use the predicate logic equivalence : For all x, phi(x) <--> there is no x such that ~ phi(x)   )

(4) The set of interpretations in which premisses P1, P2, P3...Pn are all true is included in the set of interpretations in whic Q is true.

( Here, the universe is I= the set of all possible interpretations)